# Can't create composite primary keys using waterline

Tags: javascript, mysql, sails.js, waterline

It seems that **waterline-mysql** doesn't allow composite primary keys to be created.

Is there any way of working around it, since I am building an app on the top of an existing database?

Answer (score 1):

**waterline-mysql** doesn't allow composite primary keys. I just saw that some days ago they've re-opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/109 so I think they are going to implement it.